# This computer is not authorized for developing on Pixel_2_API_28

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to open my project in android studio via Node.js command prompt. I wrote npm start, and when I write a to open android studio, the message "This computer is not authorized for developing on Pixel_2_API_28" appeared. How do I solve it?

I tried restart the command prompt and android studio, but the problem persisted.